# Aggregation in mongoengine returns $geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm trying to use *$geoNear* in an aggregation pipeline.

Running it from mongo shell likewise works fine:

`db.base_model.aggregate([{$geoNear: {near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [10.634584, 35.8245029]}, distanceField: "coordinates"}}])`.

But running using mongoengine like this

```
model.objects.aggregate(*[{"$geoNear": {"near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [10.634584, 35.8245029]}, "distanceField": "coordinates"}}])
```

returns the following error **$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline** even if $geoNear is the ONLY stage in the pipeline. Any idea why is this happening?

Using:

- mongoengine: 0.17.0
- MongoDB server version: 4.4.0

Comment: More likely you are misusing mongoengine, less likely it doesn't support this. Find relevant documentation, ensure you are following it, add to question.

Comment: There is no official documentation for this. All other stages like $match and $project work fine except for $geoNear. Mongoengine's official documentation states that "MongoEngine provides a wrapper around the built-in methods and provides some of its own, which are implemented as Javascript code that is executed on the database server."

Comment: So where is this documentation?

Comment: https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#aggregation

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the github sibling [ticket](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2473), MongoEngine is actually adding stage to the pipeline in case you have skip/limit/sort or a filter defined on your queryset. It is probably what is clashing in your case

Answer (score 0):

A working **$geoNear** example that works under *mongoengine*.

```
from mongoengine import *

connect()


class Aggr(Document):
    name = StringField()
    c = PointField()


Aggr(name='X', c=[10.634584, 35.8245029]).save()
Aggr(name='Y', c=[10.634584, 35.8245029]).save()

pipeline = [
    {"$geoNear": {
        "near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [10.634584, 35.8245029]}, "distanceField": "c",
        "spherical": True
    }}
]
print(list(Aggr.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)))
```